# Back button in Application bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to ask how to add a "back" button to the app bar.

My app bar looks like this:

[My App bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcWcQ.png)

But i would like to place this arrow to the my app bar before title.

[Arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gqKT.png)

This is my Styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in the Avtivity that you want to show the back button

```
//onCreate
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
   actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
   actionBar.setTitle("title");
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: "onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)" is not in onCreate! just under onCreate

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with the `Toolbar`, it is as simple as

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```